# What are some products that are now words?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

All of the ones I can think of are specific products that have come to represent their kind. This is usually either because it is the first of its kind, as in a Xerox machine (the first office photocopier), or it arises from popularity, as in Sharpie or something like "Google that" (though I'd say that's a bit informal/debatable).

Other examples I can think of off the top of my head are:

- Kleenex
- Post-it

Comment: -1 The top answer has definitively and permanently answered with a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. The second answer its trying to replicate the first link.

Answer (score 13):

What you are looking for is called a [*genericized trademark*, *generic trademark*, or *proprietary eponym*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark), and Wikipedia has a huge list:

- [List of generic and genericized trademarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks)

It includes all the examples mentioned by chaos and yourself, and many more.

See also this related question:

- [What is a word/phrase for using a term for a popular special case instead of a generic term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-is-a-word-phrase-for-using-a-term-for-a-popular-special-case-instead-of-a-ge)

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive answer. The Wikipedia link also covers something I was thinking of... that the usage of many of these generic trademarks may be country-specific. For instance, though I call post-its _post-its_, I don't call facial tissues _kleenex_ or vacuum cleaners _hoovers_.

Answer (score 6):

- Aqualung
- Aspirin
- Astroturf
- Band-aid
- Bubble wrap
- Butterscotch
- Cellophane
- Chapstick
- Coke (only in some regions)
- Crock pot
- Cuisinart
- Dumpster
- Dry ice
- Escalator
- Frisbee
- Jeep
- Jello
- Jetski
- Hacky sack
- Heroin
- Hoover (mainly in the UK)
- Kerosene
- Laundromat
- Linoleum
- Muzak
- Q-tip
- Tarmac
- Taser
- Thermos
- Trampoline
- Velcro
- Walkman
- Yo-yo
- Zipper

Answer (score 2):

- Duck tape
- George Foreman grill
- Palm Pilot
- Scotch tape

Comment: I think the generic usage of "duck tape" as a distortion of "duct tape" actually predates the manufacture of the Duck Tape brand of duct tape.  It's actually the phenomenon OP is asking about in reverse.

Comment: @chaos Are you sure? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_tape#Etymology

Comment: Not completely; I'm dubious of the "duck tape" origin, though hey, could be.   But even if it's true, it's an origin in a generic, not in the current Duck Tape trademarked product.  Duck Products only even claims to go back 20 years.

Comment: Scotch tape is US usage; in UK it would usually be called Sellotape.

Comment: @chimp I hear that it is called Durex in Australia - which must lead to some interesting misunderstandings.

Comment: Why would "George Foreman grill" be generic? I've never heard it used to refer to random grills.

Comment: @JohnC I have heard it used to refer to any small grill.

Answer (score 2):

- iPod (I've seen many people use iPod to refer to any MP3 player)
- Xerox
- Zip-lock

Answer (score 1):

Left out *Jacuzzi* - the generic term is *hot tub*; and perhaps *fridge*, which according to [the Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fridge&searchmode=none) is:

> shortened and altered form of refrigerator, 1926, perhaps influenced
>   by Frigidaire (1919), a popular early brand name of the appliances.

Answer (score -4):

Some of the words that I find in common use nowadays in their domain are as follows:

> 1. Blogging (Posting articles on web-logs)
> 2. Magging (Shooting)
> 3. Facebooking (Online on facebook)

Comment: I think these are just general neologisms.  Nobody ever had a trademark on "blog", did they?  Facebooking isn't a generic; nobody would say they're Facebooking while they're on Myspace.

Comment: I just meant that these are some words that are turning familiar. And yes the word "Blog" is a trademark.

Comment: *Really.*  Whose trademark is it?