# Is "hoover" capitalised?

Tags: british-english, capitalization, brands

In the UK (and sometimes Australia), a vacuum cleaner will be called a hoover, regardless of its brand. Likewise, the verb "to vacuum" is replaced with "to hoover".

With a brand name being used in such a way, does it still require a capital letter? Why or why not? Does its capitalisation depend on region?

Comment: It's really a legal matter, not a linguistic one. The same can be said for _xerox_ or _aspirin_, for example. In all these cases, popular adoption of a trademark as a generic term is something companies tried to avoid, but failed (except in the case of _Aspirin_, which is generic in the USA but not in Canada, where it's still a Bayer trademark). Nevertheless, lawyers may be deployed by the Hoover company, if it still exists.

Comment: It should be said that the generic use of "hoover" is, while not unknown, fairly rare in most parts of the US.  In fact I've only heard "hoover" used as a verb once that I can recall (and that was in the movie *Rancho Deluxe*).

Comment: @John Lawler - How would lawyers deal with colloquial usage and why? A company should be happy if their brand is converted into a generic name by people, should they not?

Comment: @javaNoobs - Tell that to Bayer, who used to own the "Aspirin" brand in the US.

Comment: @Hot Licks - I see. This is a different case, they probably wanted to force people to adopt 'Bayer' instead of 'Aspirin' and treated the term as their step child. But legal issue is only possible if I publish a text or produce a movie with 'Aspirin' used in it. If you call it 'aspirin' at home, no one cares, I guess.

Comment: @javaNoobs - No, they wanted to keep "Aspirin" as a trademark in the US and prohibit other companies from using the term.

Comment: @Hot Licks - then it is not a language usage issue, but is it possible that a brand owner goes to court for using their brand name as a verb? Can the Hoover brand owner suit Rancho Deluxe producers for using 'hoover' as a verb? I do not think so.

Comment: @javaNoobs If anything, the movie using "hoover" as a verb is great advertising for the Hoover company.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My question asks about its use as a noun, not just a verb. Also it's rather different from cheese; most cheese names are derived from towns, not companies and cheeses cannot be used as a verb.

Comment: It's answered there. The question is essentially about genericisation and the legal implications. The Hoover/hoover case is actually addressed. Look at all the answers.

Comment: I cannot add my vote to close this question as being a duplicate of the "cheese" one, because I disagree. Names of cheeses  and manufactured products are *not* the same. But I believe the second duplicate question listed, ***does*** answer this OP. What to do?

Comment: There is also [Should proper nouns used as verbs be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79038/should-proper-nouns-used-as-verbs-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Verbed brands**

No, verbs are almost never capitalized (see   Edwin Ashworth's comment for the rare cases when they are). I suggest a good article on verbing brand names on [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2010/10/verbing_brand_names):

> So ***to google*** became to search on the web, ***to facebook*** meant to look up
>   or contact someone on Facebook, and ***to skype*** covers calling someone by
>   VoIP telephony.
>
> Among photographers, meanwhile, ***to photoshop*** is common currency for
>   what you do to an image after you've snapped it

**'Genericided' brands**

As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, I missed the first part of the question about **noun capitalization**.

Normally, if a brand noun is used as a generic noun, it is not capitalized, but many companies insist on capitalization, to prevent a process called genericide which is described in a very interesting article:

"Are You Guilty of Genericide?" on [**Daily Writing Tips**](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/are-you-guilty-of-genericide/). The article deals with capitalization issue, and the point is:

- brand owners insist on capitalization but fail to achieve this
- people tend not to capitalize and this trend wins

It is disputable whether capitalization is a mistake or not. While brand owners object genericidal effect, dictionaries accept brands as generic nouns.

Comment: That's actually a really interesting source. I might have to stop capitalising Google when I say _Why don't you Google it?_

Comment: @WindowsDude7 - that's right, although spellcheckers will try to force you to capitalize

Comment: Like Google Chrome did to me whilst writing the comment.

Comment: OP asks about the noun, not just the verb. And 'verbs are never capitalized' is not true: Christianize or Christianise: verb (transitive) to make Christian or convert to Christianity/ to imbue with Christian principles, spirit, or outlook [[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/christianize); also Wiktionary; YourDictionary; Webster/WordNet ...]. Also Judaise, Islamise.