# Word for trade name that has become synonymous with the proper term for an item?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a word/phrase for using a term for a popular special case instead of a generic term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-is-a-word-phrase-for-using-a-term-for-a-popular-special-case-instead-of-a-ge)

As the title of this question indicates, I was wondering if there is a specific term that means a trademarked product name that has become synonymous with the 'proper' name of an item.

For example:

- the word *perspex*, which is used to describe PMMA (polymethyl methacrylate), even if it is not made by [ICI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Chemical_Industries),
- *biro*, which is more often than not used to describe a ballpoint pen, and
- *super glue*, which seems to be the common name for cyanoacrylate adhesives, or any other type of liquid/paste-form bonding agent of similar strength.