# what is the word or term used calling kleenex for tissues or pampers for diaper

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a word/phrase for using a term for a popular special case instead of a generic term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-is-a-word-phrase-for-using-a-term-for-a-popular-special-case-instead-of-a-g)

I remember there is an English term or word used to describe this.

Dell for computers, e.g. "I need to get a dell".

Kleenex for tissues, e.g. "Do you have a kleenex for me please?"