# Is there a word or phrase for using overspecific, incorrect language intentionally?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, humor, rhetorical-devices

A comedian I like calls vampires "Draculas", with the specificity as well as the incorrectness (there is only one Dracula, but many vampires) being a source of humor. Is there a word for this language technique? It almost feels like a relative of synecdoche.

Comment: [What is a word/phrase for using a term for a popular special case instead of a generic term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-is-a-word-phrase-for-using-a-term-for-a-popular-special-case-instead-of-a-g/32188#32188) is related but does not address comedic effect of eponymy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proper name to stand in for a common one, or vice versa, is called [antonomasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonomasia).